# Computing $\dim (\mathbb{Q} + x \mathbb{R}[x])$

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Can I compute the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Q} + x \mathbb{R}[x]$  knowing elementary facts only? (This question comes from Atiyah-MacDonald)

I know that $\dim (\mathbb{Q}[x]) = 1$ and $\dim (\mathbb{R}[x]) = 1$. Can I compute $\dim (\mathbb{Q} + x \mathbb{R}[x])$  from these two facts?

Can I compute $\dim (\mathbb{Q} + x \mathbb{R}[x])$ knowing elementary facts (Atiyah-Macdonald level)?

Comment: I've found a way to prove the existence of a maximal chain of length $1$, but I don't have a way of eliminating longer chains :( Not much help considering we already know it's at least $1$ dimensional... Possibly there is some elementary theorem about when maximal chains have the same length that would help.

Comment: What context does the question come in? Were there any theorems preceding it that seem like they might apply? I guess there must be some way to connect the chains of primes to those in $\mathbb R[x]$, or some other ring.